# How can I pass parameters to a loaded swf application?

Tags: swfloader, flex4

When I load an swf application using SWFLoader in Flex 4, how can I pass parameters to that application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this, but it looks like you can append them directly to the SWFLoader's source as a query string:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source = "map/us.swf?data_file=map/senate.xml" id="mapLoader" width="300" height="100" />
```

And retrieve them in the loaded SWF with:

```
var your_param:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.data_file;
trace(your_param);
```

[Source](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=175951)

Comment: it works.. if i want to have more then one parameter i need to seperate each parameter with &amp; instead of &